# All points on Line

Tags: math, geometry

If I draw a line from let's say: (2,3) to (42,28), how can I get all points on the line in a Point list? I tried using the slope, but I can't seem to get the hang of it.
To be clear: I would like all the pixels that the line covers. So I can make the line 'clickable'.

Comment: There is an infinite number of points between them. Your list won't cope.

Comment: There's not an infinite number of, say, pixels though.  If the coordinates are defined as integers, the list is finite.

Comment: there are two independent things here. if you just want to draw a line with (say) wpf, you don't need to calculate intermediate points, the framework will do it for you during drawing. If you want to calculate the grid dots forming the line, you should look at [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) (but again you don't need this if you just want to draw a line).

Comment: What are you trying to implement here? The solution you need will be highly dependent on that since, like it was pointed out earlier, there are an infinite number of points. So you probably just need a subset of some sort.

Comment: I would like the line to be 'clickable'. Therefore I need to know the Point of every pixel in a line.

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal: See my comment below. You don't need every pixel on the line, you only need to know if the pixel clicked is on the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a math question. The equation of a line is:

```
y = mx + c
```

So you need to figure out the gradient (m) and the intercept (c) and then plug in values for x to get values for y.

But what do you mean by "all the points on a line"? There is an infinite number of points if x and y are real numbers.

Comment: I would like the points of all the pixels of the line that is drawn to the screen. so in my example, it would be about 50 points, I quess.

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal: Then Vlad above directed you to the correct algorithm, although I'd question why you are convinced you need this? You don't mention what technology you are using beyond `C#`, but if you are, for example, using WPF, you don't need to know those points, even if you want the line to be "clickable". You can attach click handlers to lines in WPF. You are just recreating functionality that exists in a lot of libraries.

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal: Another thought, you don't need all the points on a line, you only need to know if the point clicked falls on the line (within some level of tolerance). This is easy. You know the equation of the line, so you plug in the x value for your click coordinate and see whether the y coordinate calculated matches (again, with some tolerance) the y coordinate from your click. If they match, *bingo*, you clicked the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula (x-x1)/(x1-x2) = (y-y1)/(y1-y2). And you know the points with x values ranging from 2 to 42 are on the line and their associated y values have to be found. If any of the resulting y value is not an integer then it should be approximated rightly. And if two consecutive y values differ by more than 1 then the missing y values should be mapped to the last x value.

Here is the pseudo code (tried to capture the crux of the algorithm)

```
prevY = y1

for(i=x1+1;i<=x2;++i)
{

  y = computeY(i);

  if(diff(y,prevY)>1) dump_points(prevY,y,i);

  prevY = y;

  dump_point(i,y);

}

dump_points(prevY,y2,x2);
```

I am probably not covering all the cases here (esp. not the corner ones). But the idea is that for one value of x there would could be many values of y and vice versa depending on the slope of the line. The algorithm should consider this and generate all the points.